# How can I create multivariable function plotting software

Tags: computational-geometry, mathematics

I have finished Dennis Ritchie's C book, and I would like to create my own plotting software for enhancing my programming skill,I want sources,books or anything to reach this goal.Thanks for answers.

Comment: What exactly do you want to plot?

Comment: any single variable or multi variable function,and I want to create my own data visualization tools.

Comment: I can recommend using graphics APIs like OpenGL, DirectX, Vulkan, WebGL. If you want resources on those just elaborate on which exactly and I can provide some. For a GUI, depending on which you pick from the above, there are multiple solutions, I can recommend Dear ImGUI for simplicity, or dat.GUI for WebGL.